# Select all value above latest date

Tags: sql, sequel

Please help me with one task. I want to get all data above date. It`s might be smth like this: 1. Find max date in column last_date for every Product_Name. 2. Get all rows that max(last_date)>start_date for every Product_Name group

My table:

[image: My_table1]

And what I want to get:

[image: Final_Resalt_table]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please, read this: [Ask]. You have to explain what is wrong with your SQL query and define above what date you want to select data.

Comment: It`s might be smth like this: 1. Find max date in column last_date for every Product_Name. 2. Get all rows that max(last_date)>start_date for every Product_Name group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(last_date) over (partition by product_name) as max_last_date
      from t
     ) t
where start_date > max_last_date;
```

Note that I changed the order of the comparison to match the results you specify rather than what the question describes.

Comment: yeap, this is what i need. Thx a lot. I guess current sql server is not allow me to use window functions. Is it possible to do that without it?

Comment: @VasylMykhalyuk . . . Window functions have been part of standard SQL for a long, long time and pretty much all (real) databases support them.  What database are you using under the hood?